# Regular expression to replace a word with another word on the different line unix

Tags: perl, unix, printing, sed, awk

Let A,B,C,D,E,F are the words

**input file**

```
A "\t" B

C "\t" D

E "\t" F
```

etc...

**output file:**

```
B "\t" C

D "\t" E

F "\t" etc...
```

Replace the word A with word B one the same line AND Replace the word B with word C from the next line.
Like wise for the other lines.

Any sed/awk/perl oneliner to accomplish that?

Comment: What do you replace F with? G? A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `awk` without regex:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } 
NR==1 { last=$NF; next }
      { last=last FS $1; print last; last=$NF}
END   { print $NF }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with bash

```
$ cat f
A   B
C   D
E   F

$ words=( $(<f) )

$ unset 'words[0]'

$ printf "%s\t%s\n" "${words[@]}"
B   C
D   E
F
```